# Vue.js computed setter performance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

When using Vuex, to accomplish a two way bind on my inputs, using v-model, the only I found is to use the computed property setter method.

For example, in my html:

```
<input v-model="name" ... />
```

And the computed property:

```
computed: {
  name: {
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.state.name;
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
      this.setNameAction(newValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to accomplish the two way bind between form inputs and Vuex? I'm concerned about Vue.js computed setter performance.

If not, how to I accomplish the easy two way bind using v-model, when working with a centralized store, like Vuex?

Comment: You shouldn't care about perfromance untill it is an actual problem.

Comment: The Vuex docs says your example is the proper way, so i wouldn't worry about it. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Comment: I just want to add my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/xdkvv86m/1/) of your snippet - so you can play around with it and I also think it's OK to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vuex docs says your example is the proper way, so i wouldn't worry about it.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html